# Вывод комментариев в админке только для постов текущего автора Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как на странице управления комментариями(в админке Wordpress) выводить не все комментарии, а только те, которые относятся к статьям авторизованного в текущий момент автора?

Comment: Что такое "страница комментариев"? Такого нет в ВП

Comment: http://example.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php

Comment: Если все работает, нажмите галочку)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать хук `pre_get_comments`. Пример:

```
function my_pre_get_comments( WP_Comment_Query $wp_comment_query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && is_main_query() ) {
        $wp_comment_query->query_vars['post_author'] = get_current_user_id();
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'my_pre_get_comments' );
```

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо. Я пробовал нечто подобное но у меня оно не взлетело (